# Current sensor problem

Tags: arduino, dc-dc-converter, ina219

I'm using INA219 to read the hold system current like the schematic
[image: System schematic]

The problem line in the DC-DC converter. When I use IC MP2315 DC-DC converter, INA219 seem like just read the off period of PWM switch and it value is 3mA when I read form Serial Plotter. Yesterday I changed MP2315 to LOD, value is 300mA which is acceptable. However, LOD dose not supply enough current for servo. So if I continue use MP2315, how can I read current when using INA219. If it is impossible, what should I do?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Are you trying to read the input current to the DC-DC converter? Based on your diagram, you are putting the INA219 between the input voltage source and the DC-DC converter. Please re-write your question in a clearer manner.

Comment: Add a big capacitor after the DC-DC converter